# React Type error in 'this.handleInput'. "'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation."

Tags: reactjs, typescript, onclick, typeerror

I want to get the value of a button with onClick to use it on the next page of my application. It is giving me a type error that I can't resolve.

```
function handleInput(e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) {
    console.log(e.target.value)
}

<PaymentButton
    value={'creditCard'}
    onClick={(e) => this.handleInput(e, 'value')}>

    <div className="paymentButtonIcon">
        <CreditCard size={16}/>
    </div>CREDIT CARD

</PaymentButton>
```

The `this` in the onClick gives me the error "'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation". It also says that the `handleInput` in the top 'is declared but its value is never read'. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Don't use  **this keyword** ... it will work

Comment: What is the syntax without 'this'? If I just remove 'this' it says that only one argument is expected

Comment: Do you wanna pass value **creditCard** when click the button?